# Where can I get the dummy content for the website?

Tags: website-design, design

I am trying to add  UI project in my portfolio so I though I would start with web design. For these dummy website can I get some dummy content?Plesae do not suggest lorem ipsum text because those are just text.I want complete dummy content for website with images, information architecture and text **a whole package as such**. Is there any link so something where I can find such content?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting content for personal use rather than specific resources that are useful or practical for UX design

Comment: This looks like asking for templates which could let someone see how the final version looks like. Off-topic.

Comment: No, I am asking if I could get a fake company profile or restuarent porfile or anything else to create website.

Answer (score 2):

While "Lorem-Ipsum" is industry standard, for using as dummy text. If you want something that look "real" instead of dummy text, you have to create that content by yourself. You can look into the similar websites, and get the idea of contents, that can be used.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for freely available content you can mark up into a design, and arrange into an architecture, then you could look to Wikipedia - they have a license so you can reproduce their content.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reusing_Wikipedia_content